# IFS formula not working where values are taken from a table (formula output)

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vlookup, ifs

I have the following formula: =IFS(F5="P","Yes",F5="C","No",F5="N/A","")

I have tested it out in a blank sheet, where "P", "C" and "N/A" are manually inputted and it works fine.

I have transferred it to the working sheet, where "P", "C" and "N/A" are in a table as a VLOOKUP outcome and the result is "#N/A".

I have created a copy of that column's data using the "=F5" formula and used that in the IFS formula, but still get the "#N/A" result.

I have checked the formatting of all cells and tried with both "general" and "text" without success.

Help!

I have a feeling that the formula values are pulled from the outcome of formulas, but don't understand why, and am looking for solutions to make the formula work (or an alternative formula which gives the same result).

Comment: Make sure the outputs of VLOOKUP are **exactly** what you need. Maybe some extra blanks or other special chars can alter the output. Anyways, you should add data input and expected output

Comment: The trim() function might help re the other comment.

Comment: If the VLOOKUP is returning a `#N/A` error, you will get what you describe, as well as if the value in the cell doesn't  match one of your tests.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all! I fel like an idiot, there was a rogue space in the source columns text.